# how to make new object from the duplicated part of other object in edit mode?

Tags: objects

i need to make new object from part i duplicated from other object.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select mesh and press <kbd>P</kbd>> *Selection*. In object mode, to join the mesh press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Select the part of the mesh, press <kbd>P</kbd> (separate) > *Selection*